# (How) Can I implement a method called Dispose in C++.CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I have an interface, not `IDisposable`, that has a method `void Dispose()`. I want to implement this interface in C++/CLI. It appears I can't. I have tried

```
    virtual void Finish() = IThing::Dispose 
    {}
```

but that gives a number of errors:

```
1>...: error C2039: 'Dispose': is not a member of '...IThing'
1>...: error C3653: 'Dispose': cannot be used as a named override: a function being overridden not found; did you forget to name the function explicitly, using a:: operator?
1>...: error C3766: 'MyNamespace::MyClass' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void ...IThing::Dispose(void)'
```

(anonymised). C2039 and C3766 seem entertainlingly contradictory...

Am I missing something or is this plain impossible?

While I accept it was a bad design decision, changing the interface is not an option, it is implemented by hundreds of library classes.

Comment: Yeah, tough cookies, Dispose is a reserved identifier in C++/CLI.  You can implement it by writing the destructor for the class, like ~RealThing().  You can do anything you want, like whatever the interface method is supposed to do.   But it *does* do too much, it will also call GC::SuppressFinalize() and you can't stop that.  C++/CLI class wrappers very often need the finalizer (!RealThing) since they wrap a pointer to a native C++ class.  You'd be lucky if you don't.

Comment: Pretty much the opposite of wanting to deterministically dispose of an object, I think; I don't want IDispose getting involved at all.

Comment: It is *just* a contract, it does not demand a specific implementation.  Other than the SuppressFinalize call, you're stuck with that.  Arguably it is a flaw in whatever language the interface was written in, probably something like C#, Dispose() means something special in that language as well.

Comment: Giving it a destructor does satisfy the compiler. In this case I can probably live with the side effects. Thanks.

Comment: @Hans, if  you want to put that in as an answer I'll give it the tick.

Comment: This question scares me, the only good advice is to ask the author of the interface to fix it and that is not advice that anybody appreciates.  Just write your own answer to close your question, feel free to copy my comments and flag them as Obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose is a reserved word, and can't be used in an explicit override. The best answer is to un-ask the question and change the interface.
However,

IF you can't change the interface

AND the semantics of the interface's `Dispose` are sufficently close to `IDispose::Dispose`'s

AND you can put up with all the dispose-pattern side effects it will bring,

THEN declaring a destructor for your class will create a method called Dispose that will satisfy your interface.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to actually implement an interface other than `IDisposable` with a `Dispose` method is:

1. Using another .NET language, perhaps C#, introduce a base class, perhaps abstract, that implements the `Dispose` method by forwarding to an abstract virtual function with a different name, perhaps `IThingDisposal`.
2. In C++/CLI, inherit from that base class and place your Dispose implementation in an override of the method named in step 1.

If you already had a base class, the new base class in step 1 should inherit from the old base class, creating indirect inheritance.  If you already had a base class that was implemented in the same C++/CLI assembly, you're in for a significant amount of hurt because you'll have to split the assembly into one the other language can consume and one that will consume the other language's base class.  I don't envy you.